# How to do FormArray with 2 arrays

Tags: angular, forms, formarray

I would like to make something like this. With angular FormArray. On array for the Name, one array for the Quantity. I arrive to do it for one but not for 2 :(

If someone have an idea. :)

I would like to make it like this:
[image]

PS: I didn't write all the test code i did. I just wrote the code that work for one array. I wrote it also without the button submit to simplify the code.

the Item come from a JSON file i wrote also the structure of it

Thanks you very much for your help

page.ts

```
itemForm: FormGroup;

initForm(array: InfoModel[]) {
  this.infoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    quantity: this.formBuilder.array([])
   });
}

onAddMoreItem() {
  const nameControl = this.formBuilder.control(null, Validators.required);
  this.getItemName().push(nameControl);
}

getItemName(): FormArray {
  return this.itemForm.get('name') as FormArray;
}
```

Template

```
<form [formGroup]="itemForm" (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
   <div formArrayName="name">
   <h3>Items</h3>
      <div *ngFor="let adControl of getName().controls; let i = index">
        <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">   
      </div>
   <button type="button" (click)="onAddMoreItem()">Add more item</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

JSON File

```
"item": [
   {
     "name" : [ "aaa", "bbb" ],
     "quantity" : [ "130", "60" ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Is the number of names and quantities going to be the same always? And is the nth item in the `name` array always correspond to the nth item in the `quantity` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular Reactive Forms are designed to work with a set data model. If you want the form to look and behave the way you've shown, you'd have to change the data model.

What you want is a `FormArray` that will have `FormGroup`s. Each `FormGroup` will have a `name` `FormControl` and a `quantity` `FormControl`.

So what can be done is, you can transform the actual data to make it form ready. And if you want the data in the previous format, you can again transform the form data to the structure that you want. You'll have to create two transformation methods in order to do that.

Here's how you'd go about doing that:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

interface Item {
  name: Array<string>;
  quantity: Array<string>;
};

interface Data {
  item: Array<Item>;
};

interface FormItem {
  name: string;
  quantity: string;
};

interface FormData {
  data: Array<FormItem>;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = {
    item: [
      {
        name: ["aaa", "bbb"],
        quantity: ["130", "60"]
      }
    ]
  };

  formData;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const formData = this.transformDataToFormData(this.data);
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      data: this.fb.array(formData.data.map((datum: FormItem) => this.fb.group({
        name: [datum.name],
        quantity: [datum.quantity]
      })))
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.data = this.transformFormDataToData(this.form.value);
  }

  addItem() {
    this.formDataArray.push(this.fb.group({
      name: [],
      quantity: []
    }));
  }

  removeItem(itemIndex: number) {
    this.formDataArray.removeAt(itemIndex);
  }

  private transformDataToFormData(data: Data): FormData {
    return {
      data: data.item[0].name
        .map(
          (name: string, index: number) => ({ name, quantity: data.item[0].quantity[index] }))
    };
  }

  private transformFormDataToData(formData: FormData): Data {
    return {
      item: [{
        name: formData.data.map((datum: FormItem) => datum.name),
        quantity: formData.data.map((datum: FormItem) => datum.quantity),
      }]
    };
  }

  private get formDataArray(): FormArray {
    return (<FormArray>this.form.controls['data']);
  }

}
```

And the template would look something like this:

```
<form 
  [formGroup]="form"
  (submit)="onFormSubmit()">
  <div 
    formArrayName="data"
    *ngFor="let item of form.controls['data'].controls; let i = index;"
    >
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="text" formControlName="name">
      <input type="text" formControlName="quantity">
      <button type="button" (click)="removeItem(i)">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="addItem()">Add new Item</button>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<hr>

<h2>Form Data</h2>

<pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>

<h2>Data</h2>
<p>This will only reflect after Submit</p>
<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-forms-with-a-different-data-structure) for your ref.